# Are there open set $U\subset X$ and $g,h \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ with $h\not = 0$, such that $\left.f\right|_U= g/h$?

Tags: analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let be $X$ a topological space and $f:X \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.  Are there open set $U\subset X$ and $g,h \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ with $h\not = 0$, such that $\left.f\right|_U= g/h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X=\Bbb R$ and $f=e^x$. Suppose there were an open set $U$ so that the claim was true: then after multiplying, we would get $h(x)e^x=g(x)$ for some polynomials $g,h$. Taking the derivative $\deg_x(g)+1$ times, we see that we would have an equation of the form $e^xp(x)=0$ holds on $U$ with $p(x)$ a nonzero polynomial. But this is impossible: $e^x\neq 0$, and a nonzero polynomial only has finitely many roots.